# Select all tables without information_schema

Tags: mysql

I'm working on Mysql Version `3`, where there is no `information_schema`.

Is there a query that can be used to get the same result of this query:

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! Back in the olden days of MySQL 3, I think the only equivalent we had was the `SHOW TABLES` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements. (And we had to do a `USE db` to change the current database to run a `SHOW TABLES` from that database.)

Comment: Show Tables can work but it can not be used with select , so it can not achieve my goal